# Validate File Names before Triggering UploadCollection

Tags: sapui5

How do I catch the file names early, validate the filename formats, and if at least one filename format has a comma, show an error and stop the whole UploadCollection operation. Please be advised a user may upload drag and drop multiple files at once.

```
<UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="100" maximumFileSize="10000000" multiple="true" instantUpload="true"
                                sameFilenameAllowed="false" uploadEnabled="true" uploadTerminated="fileUploadTerminated"
                                showSeparators="All" change="onUploadChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts"
                                uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" mode="SingleSelectMaster"
                                visible="true"></UploadCollection>
```

UploadCollection ends up uploading the files

```
 onBeforeUploadStarts: function (oEvent) {
            // validate here and if validation fails, return. ----> This solution doesn't work
                var slug = oEvent.getParameter("fileName") + "," + this.sRequestID + "," + this.oData.VendNum + "," + reqHeaderTms + ",RFU"; 
                var oCustomerHeaderSlug = new UploadCollectionParameter({
                    name: "slug",
                    value: slug
                });
                oEvent.getParameters().addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderSlug);
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can stop the upload operation for the UploadCollection via the onUploadChange event.

```
fileUploadTerminated: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("fileUploadTerminated");
},
onUploadChange: function(oEvent) {
    var files = oEvent.getParameter("files");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if ( /*... Condition XYZ ...*/ ) {
            this.getView().byId("UploadCollection").removeItem(files[i].name); 
            this.getView().byId("UploadCollection").fireUploadTerminated({
                fileName: files[i].name
            });
            oEvent.preventDefault();
            return; // ----> IMPORTANT
        }
    }
},
onBeforeUploadStarts: function(oEvent) {
    if ( /*... Condition XYZ ...*/ ) {
        oEvent.preventDefault(); // The oEvent object contains the item - file whose upload is just about to start.
        return; // ----> Important
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of the event.

```js
onBeforeUploadStarts: function (oEvent) {
  // validate
  if (/*...*/) {
    oEvent.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  // ...
},
```

The `oEvent` object contains the item - file whose upload is just about to start.

More info about the event: https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.upload.UploadSet#events/beforeUploadStarts

Comment: Unfortunately, the file whose upload is just about to start still flows to the backend.  The above solution fails to stop the upload process

Comment: Then why did you accept it @FahmiEshaq?

Comment: @FahmiEshaq, I now noticed that you are using the deprecated sap.m.UploadCollection control. Its 'beforeUploadStarts' event cannot be prevented. After version 1.88 it is recommended to use the sap.m.upload.UploadSet control. The solution I have posted is for the UploadSet.

Comment: @PetarDimov Ok thanks. For UploadCollection, we can hande it in onUploadChange

Comment: Your answer helped me reach a conclusion.